# sed question insert colons

Tags: sed

Hello I want to use sed to search a file for 3-5 alpha chars followed by 3 numbers and insert a colon after the first alpha char and a colon before the numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU sed on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS:

```
sed -r -e 's/([a-zA-Z]{3,5})([0-9]{3})/\1:\2/g'
```

EDIT: Misread the OP's question. Better answer:

```
sed -r -e 's/([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]{2,4})([0-9]{3})/\1:\2:\3/g'
```

Comment: If you expect the strings `abcdef123` or `abcde1234` to fail, you may want to amend the regex to include word boundaries, like so: `sed -r 's/(\<[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]{2,4})([0-9]{3}\>)/\1:\2:\3/g`